# Mime type checking of files uploaded Golang

Tags: go, mime-types

I am trying to get the mime type of files being uploaded in my server.

The .xlsx and .docx files mime type comes up application/zip. I tried to unzip the file and read the file of type "_rels/.rels". The doubt that I have is while reading this particular file, what should the maximum size that I should leave for the reading the file, and if the Target is "xl/workbook.xml" can I assume it to be of type xlsx?

My code is as below

```
 file, fileHeader, err := r.FormFile("file")

buffer := make([]byte, 512)
_, err = file.Read(buffer)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

contentType := http.DetectContentType(buffer)
if contentType == "application/zip" {
    r, err := zip.NewReader(file, fileHeader.Size)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    for _, zf := range r.File {
        if zf.Name == "_rels/.rels" {
            fmt.Println("rels")
            rc, err := zf.Open()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Rels errors")
            }
            const BufferSize = 1000
            buffer := make([]byte, BufferSize)
            defer rc.Close()
            bytesread, err := rc.Read(buffer)
            if err != nil {
                if err != io.EOF {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                }
            }

            fmt.Println("bytes read: ", bytesread)
            fmt.Println("bytestream to string: ", string(buffer[:bytesread]))
            fmt.Println(rc)
        }
    }
}


var arr []byte
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
w.Write(arr)
```

}

the output I get is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Relationships     xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties" Target="docProps/app.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId2" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships/metadata/core-properties" Target="docProps/core.xml"/><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="xl/workbook.xml"/></Relationships>
```

Any tips on how to read a .doc or .xls ?

Comment: If the content type header isn't being properly set, the next best is probably to use the file extension.

Comment: The issue is when people change the file extension and upload, I am trying to do a check of it. I am able to solve the .docx, .xlsx files.

Comment: If you're just trying to read .xlsx files, don't re-invent the wheel and use a library like [excelize](https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize).

Comment: I need to find out the type of file being uploaded. I am able to find out if it is a .docx or .xlsx. I am unable to find out the mime types of binary files such as .doc or .cls

Comment: The defer will not close the files until the end of the function call. You can close them at the end of the loop instead.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unfortunately `DetectContentType` from the `html` package is rather limited to the mime types it can detect.

As for detecting binary formats, you don't need to read the whole file if all you need is to tell if it is a .doc. You can just check the file signature. A good resource for file signatures is [file signatures](https://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html)

If you instead want to use existing packages, this is a summary of what's on github.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of [mimetype](https://github.com/gabriel-vasile/mimetype).

- [filetype](https://github.com/h2non/filetype)

  - pure go, no c bindings
  - can be extented to detect new mime types
  - has issues with files which pass as more than one mime type (ex: xlsx and docx passing as zip) because it stores matching functions in a map, thus it does not guarantee the order of traversal
- [magicmime](https://github.com/rakyll/magicmime)

  - needs libmagic-dev installed
  - can be extended, albeit harder... `man magic`
- [mimetype](https://github.com/gabriel-vasile/mimetype)

  - pure go, no c bindings
  - higher number of detected mime types than `filetype`
  - is thread safe
  - can be extended

Comment: Tried mimetype.DetectReader, it seems to changing the seek position of the passed reader which is corrupting the caller file.

Comment: @krsoni if the buffer is a Seeker you can rewind, setting the position back to 0 offset

Answer (score 2):

you can using.

```
import (
"net/http"
"os"
)

filebytes, err :=os.Readfile(filePath)

http.DetectContentType(filebytes)
```